# How to listen a frame property of a view on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view and I added a observer like this:

```
_aView = [UIView new];
[_aView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
_aView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

In the observer method I get the new value :

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", change[@"new"]);
    }
  }
```

The log is `NSRect: {{100, 100}, {100, 100}}`. 
The question is that I got the value type is `NSRect`, how to convert it to `CGRect`?

In the UIKit library have no type named `NSRect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSRect` and `CGRect` are the same on OS X. You will find this in `NSGeometry.h` in the OS X SDK:

```
typedef CGRect NSRect;
```

On iOS, `NSRect` doesn't exist, but the formatting function is the same on both platforms and it prints `NSRect` regardless. You can get the `CGRect` value like this:

```
CGRect rect = [change[@"new"] CGRectValue];
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, my answer is not correct, but got +1. I was not aware that NSRectToCGRect is missing in iOS

Answer (score 2):

Convert `NSRect` to `CGRect` by:

```
CGRect NSRectToCGRect(NSRect nsrect);
```

Note: [NSRect doesn't exist in iOS](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/nsrect-in-ios/), the above works in only in OSX.

**For iOS**: `CGRect rect = [change[@"new"] CGRectValue];` //copied from Rob's answer

Read [Rect Conversion in iOS](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2007/03/15/rect_conversion/).